# Understanding versioning with MySQL and MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to understand the relationship between MySQL versions and MariaDB versions and hoping someone can clarify?

I was under the impression that MariaDB was forked from MySQL many years ago and, as such, are independent projects, however...

When I install mariadb:10.0.38, version is shown as `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.38-MariaDB`

When I install mariadb:5.5.65, version is shown as `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.65`

SO... what is the 15.1 referring to? AFAIK MySQL is only on version 8 and MariaDB is only on 10?

Can anyone help with an explanation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you get that version string from?

Comment: I used `mysql -V`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql -V` returns the version of the `mysql` client command used to access a MySQL server (here 15.1), as well as the version of MySQL (or MariaDB) it was distributed with, not (directly) the version of the server itself.

For the authoritative server version, run `SELECT VERSION();` within `mysql`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, makes total sense.